# Downloader and installer in one application, MS Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, download

I am working on a launcher application in Visual Studio, using C#, that has an option to download and install app.

Now the problem is, since I want to keep everything in the same app, how do I make the installer? I can easily make a setup as separate app, but that is not what I need, I need to integrate the installer in my launcher, so after files are downloaded it should automatically start installation process in background and report progress to progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer:

The download part is straightforward - you do the download and report the status to a progress bar.

Installing the setup is more complicated. Many require user input, so you can't just show a progress bar without showing the installer's UI, which mean that that the install owns the progress bar as well. So assuming that these setups have no requirement for user input, showing progress depends on what kind of setup it is. If it's MSI-based, for example, then there is an API based on MsiSetExternalUIRecord but there is more than just progress to show. If there are errors, files-in-use situations, all of which can happen during the progress phase, you own the UI and you need to deal with them. There's more to the install than just a progress bar. That's probably true of any setup.  So it's not clear exactly what you're looking for because setups own their own UI and usually require user input, and require error reporting while they are installing, also they can fail and rollback, so should the progress bar go backwards too?

It's also not clear what you expect when setups require prerequisites like SQL, NET Framework, VC++ runtimes etc to be installed.

Short answer:

If you use WiX and a Burn bootstrapper pretty much all of this already exist, so I'd see if that meets your requirements instead of doing it all from scratch.

Comment: Okay, I will take time to look into Burn bootstrapper, but to explain in more detail what I need:
So basically, I have this app written in c#, it downloads and reports progress, once package is downloaded, it should run the installer somehow in background without the UI, because I already have an app that contains all the UI required, so I would need to somehow access variables from the setup, or integrate setup code into my app so that I Can report progress or check for any errors.